# How do i get this web app to use the up joystick button as an input

Tags: javascript, windows, joystick, browser

There is this reaction time test app that calculates the reaction time from the time you press a button, it works with the joystick buttons except for the directional buttons, this is the app:

https://humanbenchmark.com/tests/reactiontime

Is there any way to make it take inputs from one of the "up", "down", "left" or "right" buttons?

Many thanks for your help

Comment: Hi! Check the [help] for more information on how to get help here. Currently your question doesn't show us what you've tried and what problems you're having with that.

Comment: Can you clarify, are you the creator of this app or trying to create such an app of your own? Or are you a user of the app trying to customize it to work in your hardware/software/preference environment? This site is only for the former - we help game developers develop their own new games and game mods. Questions players have about *playing* games can be asked on [Arqade](https://gaming.stackexchange.com), while questions about how to customize software can often find a home on [Super User](https://superuser.com). Be sure to check both sites' help sections before posting to stay on-topic.